# How to reload tawk.to widget on language change using i18next?

Tags: javascript, jquery, translation, i18next, tawk.to

I handle language switching with i18n-jquery and I also use tawk.to chat widget. I have managed to load different languages for the widget on page reload, but since i18n does not reload the page and I don't want to reload the page I need to reload the widget on it's own.

```
function loadChatBox(){ 
    var lang = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lang'))
    var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
    (function(){
    var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s1.async=true;
    if(lang == 'en'){
        s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/.../asset1';
    }else{
        s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/.../asset2';
    }
    s1.charset='UTF-8';
    s1.id = "chatBox";
    s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
    s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
    })();
}
```

This is my current tawk embed, I tried putting it inside the function to call it on language change, but the widget does not change to a different asset. I did log out `s0` and on language change the asset changes in the script `src` but the widget itself does not. I'm guessing I need to reload the widget but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such feature in Tawk.to